# Add Calendar value to object in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to build a basic Spring application to take information about a teaching session and add it to a MySQL database.

A form is displayed, the user inputs the values and clicks submit, which sends the values to my controller via POST. The values should be stored in a Session object.

This works fine for all the values, except for the Date (start_date, end_date) and Time (start_time, end_time) variables, which remain null and their setters are not called.

**How can I make it store the received values into the required Date and Time values?**

This is my jsp file containing the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Add a new session | Undergraduate Teaching System</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/main.css">
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>
        <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->

    <h1>Add a new teaching session</h1>

    <form action="addsessionresult" method="POST">

        <!-- Course -->
        <label for="course">Course:</label>
        <select name="course">
            <option>Course 1</option>
            <option>Course 2</option>
            <option>Course 3</option>
            <option>Course 4</option>
            <option>Course 5</option>            
        </select>    
        <br />
        <!-- Sesion name -->
        <label for="session_name">Sesion name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="session_name" />
        <br />
        <!-- Date picker -->           
        <label for="datepicker">Start date:</label>
        <input type="text" class="date_picker" name="start_date" />
        <br />

        <!-- Repeat frequency -->
        <label for="session_frequency">Repeat every:</label>  
        <select name="session_frequency" id="session_frequency">
            <option value="0">One-off event</option>
            <option value="1">1 week</option>
            <option value="2">2 weeks</option>
            <option value="3">3 weeks</option>
            <option value="4">4 weeks</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <div id="repeat_until_wrapper" class="hidden">
            <label for="end_date">Repeat until:</label>  
            <input type="text" class="date_picker" name="end_date" />
            <br />
        </div>

        <!-- Time -->
        <label for="start_time">Start time:</label>
        <select name="start_time">
            <option value="09:00">09:00</option>
            <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
            <option value="11:00">11:00</option>
            <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
            <option value="13:00">13:00</option>
            <option value="14:00">14:00</option>
            <option value="15:00">15:00</option>
            <option value="16:00">16:00</option>
            <option value="17:00">17:00</option>
            <option value="18:00">18:00</option>
            <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
            <option value="20:00">20:00</option>                
        </select>
        <br />
        <!-- Duration -->
        <label for="session_duration">Duration:</label>
        <select name="session_duration">
            <option value="15">15m</option>
            <option value="30">30m</option>
            <option value="45">45m</option>
            <option value="60" selected>1h</option>
            <option value="75">1h 15m</option>
            <option value="90">1h 30m</option>
            <option value="105">1h 45m</option>
            <option value="120">2h</option>
            <option value="135">2h 15m</option>
            <option value="150">2h 30m</option>
            <option value="165">2h 45m</option>
            <option value="180">3h</option>
            <option value="195">3h 15m</option>
            <option value="210">3h 30m</option>
            <option value="225">3h 45m</option>
            <option value="240">4h</option>
            <option value="255">4h 15m</option>
            <option value="270">4h 30m</option>
            <option value="285">4h 45m</option>
            <option value="300">5h</option>                
        </select>
        <br />
        <!-- Lecturer -->
        <label for="staff_member">Staff member:</label>
        <select name="staff_member">
            <option>Stephen Smith</option>
            <option>Matthew Brown</option>  
            <option>Gethin Black</option>
            <option>Jeremy Bailey</option>
            <option>Joseph Lewis</option>
            <option>David Watson</option>
        </select>    
        <br />
        <!-- Max attendance -->
        <label for="max_attendance">Max. attendance:</label>
        <input type="number" name="max_attendance" />
        <br />
        <!-- Compulsory -->
        <label for="compulsory">Is compulsory?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="compulsory" />
        <br />
        <!-- Venue -->
        <label for="venue">Venue:</label>
        <select name="venue">
            <option value="Building 513">Building 513</option>
            <option value="Building 720">Building 720</option>
            <option value="Building 811">Building 811</option>
        </select>
        <br /><br />
        <button type="submit" name="submit_data">Add session</button>            
    </form>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/vendor/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/js/main.js"></script>

</body>
```

This is my controller:

```
//Gets the information from the new session form.
@RequestMapping(value = "/addsessionresult")
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView addSession(@ModelAttribute("session") Session session, BindingResult result){
    try {
        //session's start_time, end_time, start_date, end_date are null here. All other variables are loaded correctly.
        DatabaseAdapter.executeSQLUpdate("INSERT INTO Session (Course, Name, StartTime, EndTime, Frequency, Staff, MaxAttendance, Compulsory, Venue, StartDate, EndDate) "
                + "VALUES (" + 
                session.getCourse() + ", " + 
                session.getSession_name() + ", " + 
                session.getStart_time() + ", " + 
                session.getSession_end_time() + ", " + 
                session.getSession_frequency() + ", " + 
                session.getStaff_member() + ", " +  
                session.getMax_attendance() + ", " +  
                session.isCompulsory() + ", " +  
                session.getVenue() + ", " +  
                session.getStart_date() + ", " +  
                session.getEnd_date() + ", " +  
                ")");
        //return "Added successfully!";
        return new ModelAndView("addsessionresult", "result", "User was added");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //return "Adding failed! Error: " + e.getMessage();
        return new ModelAndView("addsessionresult", "result", "User not added\r\n\r\nError: \n" +e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is my Session class:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Session {
private String course, session_name;
private Calendar start_date, end_date;
private int session_frequency;
private Time start_time, end_time;
private String staff_member;
private int max_attendance, session_duration;
private boolean compulsory;
private String venue;

public ArrayList<Calendar> getDates(){
    ArrayList<Calendar> dates = new ArrayList<Calendar>();
    if (session_frequency > 0) {
        for (Calendar d = start_date; !d.after(end_date); d.add(Calendar.DATE, session_frequency)){
            dates.add((Calendar) d.clone());
        }
    } else {
        dates.add(start_date);
    }
    return dates;
}

public void setSession_duration(Time start_time, Time end_time) {
    //TODO probably needs fixing.
    int i = 0;
}

public String[] toArray(){
    String[] result = new String[6];
    result[0]  = "Course: " + course;
    result[1]  = "Session: " + session_name;
    result[2]  = "Time: " + start_time.toString().substring(0, 5) + " - " + end_time.toString().substring(0, 5);
    result[3]  = "Staff: " + staff_member;
    if (compulsory) {
        result[4]  = "Attendance is compulsory";
    } else {
        result[4]  = "Attendance is not compulsory";
    }
    result[5] = "Venue: " + venue;

    return result;
}

public String[] toArray(Calendar date){
    SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
    String[] result = new String[7];
    result[0]  = "Course: " + course;
    result[1]  = "Session: " + session_name;
    result[2]  = "Date: " + sdfDate.format(date.getTime());
    result[3]  = "Time: " + start_time.toString().substring(0, 5) + " - " + end_time.toString().substring(0, 5);
    result[4]  = "Staff: " + staff_member;
    if (compulsory) {
        result[5]  = "Attendance is compulsory";
    } else {
        result[5]  = "Attendance is not compulsory";
    }
    result[6] = "Venue: " + venue;

    return result;
}

public String getCourse() {
    return course;
}
public void setCourse(String course) {
    this.course = course;
}
public String getSession_name() {
    return session_name;
}
public void setSession_name(String session_name) {
    this.session_name = session_name;
}
public Calendar getStart_date() {
    return start_date;
}
public void setStart_date(Calendar start_date) {
    this.start_date = start_date;
}
public void setStart_date(String start_date) {
    System.out.println("Damn, start date");
    try {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(start_date));
        setStart_date(cal);
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}
public Calendar getEnd_date() {
    return end_date;
}
public void setEnd_date(Calendar end_date) {
    this.end_date = end_date;
}
public void setEnd_date(String end_date) {
    try {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
        cal.setTime(sdf.parse(end_date));
        setEnd_date(cal);
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}
public int getSession_frequency() {
    return session_frequency;
}
public void setSession_frequency(int session_frequency) {
    //Transform to weeks.
    this.session_frequency = 7 * session_frequency;
}
public Time getStart_time() {
    return start_time;
}
public void setStart_time(String start_time) {
    this.start_time = Time.valueOf(start_time);
}
public void setStart_time(Time start_time) {
    this.start_time = start_time;
}
public Time getSession_end_time() {
    return end_time;
}
public void setSession_end_time(Time session_end_time) {
    this.end_time = session_end_time;
}
public int getSession_duration() {
    return session_duration;
}
public void setSession_duration(int session_duration) {
    //I hate Java's Time / Date / Calendar / etc. classes!!!
    //Update end time.
    /*Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(start_time);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, session_duration);
    end_time.setTime(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    */
    this.session_duration = session_duration;
}
public String getStaff_member() {
    return staff_member;
}
public void setStaff_member(String staff_member) {
    this.staff_member = staff_member;
}
public int getMax_attendance() {
    return max_attendance;
}
public void setMax_attendance(int max_attendance) {
    this.max_attendance = max_attendance;
}
public boolean isCompulsory() {
    return compulsory;
}
public void setCompulsory(boolean compulsory) {
    this.compulsory = compulsory;
}
public String getVenue() {
    return venue;
}
public void setVenue(String venue) {
    this.venue = venue;
}
}
```

Comment: The way you execute your SQL leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Please read: [Defending Against SQL Injection Attacks](http://download.oracle.com/oll/tutorials/SQLInjection/index.htm)

Comment: Can you add the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the `Session` table? Do you get an exception or are the values simply `null` after your insert?

Comment: @reto, I am aware of that, but this code will not go into production so it does not matter.
The session object has the Date and Time values NULL before reaching the INSERT command. It has nothing to do with the way it is handled by the DatabaseAdapter class.

Comment: Don't have two setters named the same way, and taking a different argument type. After renaming one of them, make sure that your JSP uses the name corresponding with the setter taking a String as argument.

Comment: Indeed JB Nizet, this along with the getters having the same return type as the setters' parameters fixed the problem. Please post it as an answer so I can mark it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have two setters named the same way, and taking a different argument type. After renaming one of them, make sure that your JSP uses the name corresponding with the setter taking a String as argument.

Comment: Also, the getters need to have the same return type as the setters' parameters. This fixed the problem, thank you!